# Is there a way to override default CSS of HTML5 form validation messages

Tags: css, html, validation, background

I want to change background of bubble message - to be red and text to be in another language , not english. I've set "required" to my input fields and CSS for valid and invalid and it's working.
And how to make this bubble message to appear when you hover input field.I tried with:

```css
 ::-webkit-validation-bubble-message {
     border: 1px solid #E6C700;
     background: #FF0000;

    }
```

But it doesn't change. How to change background of bubble messages?
My CSS for valid and invalid is:

```css
input:focus:invalid, select:focus:invalid { 
    background: #fff url("images/required.png") no-repeat 98% center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
    border-color: #b03535
}
 input:required:valid, select:required:valid { 
    background: #fff url("images/valid.png") no-repeat 98% center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
    border-color: #28921f;
}
```

Comment: On the message as in "Please enter something in the input" and you want it to be with a background and a different color?

Comment: Well i did a quick search on google,seems like most people change it with JavaScript so you might want to take a look at that.Maybe try this 
http://demosthenes.info/blog/697/Customizing-HTML5-Form-Error-Messages-With-JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

Will only partially work on chrome and safari.

ultimately you can not style these at the moment the are browser/OS specific.

You can change the messages with JS but that's as much as you can get away with at the moment.

Comment: It doesn't change when I use it in chrome.

Comment: Like I said it will only partially work. You have no chance of styling them.

Comment: I tried with this to change text: var email = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

            email.oninvalid = function(e) {

            e.target.setCustomValidity("");

            if (!e.target.validity.valid) { e.target.setCustomValidity("Field is required"); }   But how to make it works for all input type = text and input type select?

            };

Comment: I don't think you can you need to specify the type in order to change it.

Comment: I specify it: But it's not working. I'm new to jQuery: $.("input[type='text']").each(function(){ var email = $("input[type='text']", this);
            email.oninvalid = function(e) {

            e.target.setCustomValidity("");

            if (!e.target.validity.valid) { e.target.setCustomValidity("Field is required"); }

            };
});

Comment: input type text wont work I dont think would have to be a type that can be validated like email

Comment: I don't have email. I just tried this code to see if it's working. My fields are dropdowns and input type text.

Comment: I mean that: But it's wrong. How to use each function for each input type text? $.("input[type='text']").each(function(){var text = $("input[type='text']", this);
            text.oninvalid = function(e) {

            e.target.setCustomValidity("");

            if (!e.target.validity.valid) { e.target.setCustomValidity("Field is required"); }

            };
});

Comment: It would have to be a validatable field type

Comment: It was working, but in this way: But I have to make it works for all input type text fields:   var text = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');text.oninvalid = function(e) {

            e.target.setCustomValidity("");

            if (!e.target.validity.valid) { e.target.setCustomValidity("Полето е задължително"); }

            };